# Would writing a server in 64bit Java be stunted by JVM heapsize / memory?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

It looks like 32 bit java program can only use between 1-2 gigs of ram?

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/javasdk/tools/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.java.doc.igaa%2F_1vg00014884d287-11c3fb28dae-7ff6_1001.html

Could I expect a java program running in 64bit OS to not have this limitation?

Comment: You don't only need a 64-bit OS, but also a 64-bit JRE. (Note that on 64-bit x86 systems you can also install a 32-bit JRE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could I expect a java program running in 64bit OS to not have this limitation?

Yes, it should be fine. However, it makes sense to check on the system you actually want to run on. There's nothing like being sure...

Comment: How would you go about checking this?  What do you mean?  Thanks

Comment: @iForgotMyLogin: Um, write a program which tries to use lots of memory, e.g. 8GB. Try to run it on a 64-bit machine with over 8GB of memory. See if it works or not. (The easiest way to use of lots of memory is to allocate lots of byte arrays of, say 1MB per array.)